# ConcurrentModificationException with Maven 3.3.3 and Sonar Maven plugin 2.6

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Java 7 
Maven 3.3.3 
Sonar plugin 2.6

```
[02:41:27][com.company:company] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project company: null: MojoExecutionException: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
[02:41:27][com.company:company] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project company: null
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:189)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] ... 13 more
[02:41:27][com.company:company] Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:394)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:405)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getCompileClasspathElements(MavenProject.java:351)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.MavenProjectConverter.populateLibraries(MavenProjectConverter.java:368)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.MavenProjectConverter.synchronizeFileSystemAndOtherProps(MavenProjectConverter.java:322)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.MavenProjectConverter.merge(MavenProjectConverter.java:223)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.MavenProjectConverter.configureModules(MavenProjectConverter.java:183)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.MavenProjectConverter.configure(MavenProjectConverter.java:113)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.collectProperties(RunnerBootstraper.java:150)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:130)
[02:41:27][com.company:company] ... 16 more
```

When fallbacked Maven to 3.1 it started working.

Side questiosn:
- Is there a way to provide bugs to Sonar without posting stackoverflow?
Unable to register account under : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR

Comment: Not a member? To request an account, please contact your JIRA administrators. You are not a member of that JIRA speicifc

Comment: Use the google group, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube, for bug reporting